# What's wrong with my return statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

Why this code is wrong ? When I change `"else if(this.power >= p)"` into only `"else"`, it's right. Can anybody give me a hint?

```
public boolean useBattery(double p) {
    if(this.power < p) {
        this.power = 0.0;
        return false;
    } else if(this.power >= p) {
        this.power = this.power - p;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like not all the paths are covered. Make sure to always use `return` as the last statement in your method, avoid having multiple `return` statements per branch.

Comment: How do you conclude the code is "wrong"? Do you get an error? Unexpected output?

Comment: What do you mean what's wrong? Do you get an error? Or is it behaving differently than you expect?

Comment: I think it's a compile error - the compiler doesn't deduce that one of the two conditions must be true.  What if either `this.power` or `p` is `NaN`?

Comment: Why do you add `if(this.power >= p)` anyway? Compiler doesn't check your conditions, so it is the same as `if(condition1){...} else if(condition2){...}` so compiler assumes that theoretically can exist scenario in which neither `condition1` or `condition2` will be true and in this scenario there will be no return.

Comment: If neither of these conditions are met, you will return an error because you have not accounted for this probability. The "Else" statement isn't testing for anything and will just return the specified result if all other conditions are not met.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To a human reader looking at the code it seems that either the first `return` will be hit, or the second, but the compiler can't be sure. To the compiler it looks like:

```
 if (condition1) {
     ...
     return false;
 } else if (condition2) {
     ...
     return true;
 }
```

and it needs to know, what will the method return if neither `condition1` nor `condition2` is true?

Whereas if you change it to a straight `else`,

```
if (condition1) {
    ...
    return false;
} else {
    ...
    return true;
}
```

then it is certain that one of the two `return` statements must be hit.

In fact in your method there is a chance that neither condition will be met: if one of the numbers you are comparing is `NaN` (the special floating point value representing "not a number"), then both of your `if` conditions will be false, and the method would have no return value.

There is also theoretically a possibility that some code running in another thread might alter the value of `this.power` between the first `if` check and the second, which could lead to both conditions evaluating to false. So it is not possible for the compiler to know for certain that one of the conditions will be met, even if they *were* logically complementary.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How about now?

Comment: This is the best answer so far, because it actually mentions a case where `this.power < p` and `this.power >= p` can both be false.

Comment: And ... an even better answer would be one that mentions both cases.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if we don't enter any of your conditional branches?  Java can't determine that you'll be able to because `else if` implies that there may not be another conditional branch to check.

Phrased another way, there's an implicit `else` block that does nothing.  Since you declare a return type, having this implicit `else` block do nothing is an error.

An `else` block is always guaranteed to execute, so you will not run into the same situation with `else`, which is *probably* what you intended to use in the first place.

Think in the case of a flowchart.

- If (`this.power < p`), then

  - Set `power` to 0
  - Return false
- Else if (`this.power >= p`), then

  - Subtract `p` from `power`
  - Return true
- Else (implied)

  - Do nothing <- this is the error

Answer (score 1):

Because if you add if into the second else there might be a condition where neither of the condition will be satisfied and method will match to no return statement.

Consider this simple example:

Consider x=5; below code will match no return statement because it doesn't satisfies any condition.

```
if(x>5){
 return true;
}
else if(x < 5){
 return false;
}
```

Comment: But why? Look at the conditions.

Comment: @KirkWoll Even without threading or `NaN`, one cannot expect a compiler to be a mathematician.  It wouldn't be enough to say in the language specification "if the `if` conditions cover all possible cases", because that would be too hard, possibly requiring artificial intelligence.  So the language designers would have to work on deciding what special cases the compiler needs to handle.  And it's not worth the effort because, frankly, only beginners code like this anyway.

Comment: @ajb, I had been thinking the OP's error was runtime (since he didn't clarify).  But you're right, it would have been a compiler error and as such would fail for the reasons you outlined.

Answer (score 1):

You can reproduce this error with even shorter code:

```
 public int doSomething() {
    if(true) {
        return 0;
    }
 }
```

This method generates compiler error  `missing return statement`

Compiler doesn't perform intelligent static analysis of your code. It just checks statements according to specification.

Java Language Specification [8.4.7 "Method body"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7) states that:

> If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally.

So, compiler just checks if these statements can complete normally.

[JLS 14.9.1 "The if-then Statement"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9.1):

> If the value is true, then the contained Statement is executed; the if-then statement completes normally if and only if execution of the Statement completes normally.
>
> **If the value is false, no further action is taken and the if-then statement completes normally.**

As you can see by specification if statement can complete normally. That's why a compile-time error occurs.

On the other hand, by [JLS 14.9.2 "The if-then-else Statement"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9.2):

> If the value is true, then the first contained Statement (the one before the else keyword) is executed; the if-then-else statement completes normally if and only if execution of that statement completes normally.
>
> If the value is false, then the second contained Statement (the one after the else keyword) is executed; the if-then-else statement completes normally if and only if execution of that statement completes normally.

As you can see if-then-else completes if and only if one of its blocks completes normally. In your example both of them contain return statements.